# Had+something+been or Had+been+something?

Tags: word-order

Active sentence:

> **The mail carrier had already delivered the mail by the time I left for school this morning.**

I ought to change that sentence into passive. Here is my attempt:

> **The mail had been already delivered by the mail carrier by the time I left for school this morning.**

Is it correct? I'm not entirely sure how to put *something* (already, always, etc) in perfect tenses. I've read about the difference "have always been" and "have been always" that can be read [here](https://www.quora.com/How-and-when-do-you-use-have-always-been-and-have-been-always-Are-they-grammatically-correct). And one of the answer said both are gramatically correct depend on a context. So, is it true in my case too? Which context I should consider?

I will provide another example:

> **I read about a hunter who had been accidentally killed by another hunter.**
>
> or
>
> **I read about a hunter who had accidentally been killed by another hunter.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt is correct. Here 'already' is an adverb. It's position doesnt matter as long as it is talking about the verb or action, (here delievering the mail to you).
So, the mail had been already delievered or the mail had been delievered already is same.
The same goes for the active sentence as well :

1. The mail carrier had already delivered the mail by the time I left for school this morning.
   2)The mail carrier had delivered the mail already by the time I left for school this morning.
   Both of these are correct. so, both of the passive forms are correct as well. It just comes down to your preference